# Assertion Failed Errors at 'copyTo'. Checked image size and type

Tags: opencv

I have tried searching on this forum, reading the documentation, and googling. I could not find an answer to my question.

Below is a brief of what I am trying to do:

1. The `Mat` object `frame` (declared as a private member in the parent class `OpenCVVideoWorker`) is read from the webcam.
2. A rectangle is drawn on the frame using the position and coordinates given by the `Rect_` object `ROIbox`.
3. The region of interest is thresholded using `inRange`.
4. The thresholded image in the region of interest is converted to RGB and copied back to the output frame at the same location it was taken out from.

I use Qt for the GUI and Visual Studio as my development environment.
When I run the program, I get 'Assertion Failed' errors despite making sure that the rows, columns, and type of the images are same while using `copyTo`. The error is at `frameROIProcessed.copyTo(outputFrame(ROIbox))` (I put in console outputs at regular intervals to find this).

Could you help me find where I am going wrong?

```
void OpenCVVideoWorker::processFrame() {
    frame.copyTo(outputFrame);

    if (ROIbox.width != 0 && ROIbox.height != 0) {
        rectangle(outputFrame, Point(ROIbox.x, ROIbox.y), cvPoint(ROIbox.x + ROIbox.width, ROIbox.y + ROIbox.height), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);
    }

    Mat frameROI = frame(ROIbox);

    if (frameROI.rows != 0 && frameROI.cols != 0) {
        Mat frameROIProcessed;
        cvtColor(frameROI, frameROIProcessed, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        inRange(frameROIProcessed, Scalar(hueLow, saturationLow, brightnessLow), Scalar(hueHigh, saturationHigh, brightnessHigh), frameROIProcessed);
        cvtColor(frameROIProcessed, frameROIProcessed, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

        qInfo("1) outputFrame(ROIbox)");
        qInfo(getImageType(outputFrame(ROIbox)).c_str());
        qInfo("2) frameROIProcessed");
        qInfo(getImageType(frameROIProcessed).c_str());
        qInfo("\n");

        frameROIProcessed.copyTo(outputFrame(ROIbox));
    }
    cvtColor(outputFrame, outputFrame, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
}
```

It is called like this in a function that runs every 16ms in a thread:

```
void OpenCVVideoWorker::receiveTimerTick() {    
    // Capture video from the webcam
    videoCapture.read(frame);
    if (frame.empty()) {
        qInfo("ERROR! blank frame grabbed");
        return;
    }

    // Process the captured frame
    processFrame();

    // Send the processed frame
    QImage outputImage((const unsigned char *) outputFrame.data, outputFrame.cols, outputFrame.rows, outputFrame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    emit sendImage(outputImage);
}
```

I get the following errors at the line `frameROIProcessed.copyTo(outputFrame(ROIbox))`:

```
Initializing the worker in its constructor...
Opening camera...
1) outputFrame(ROIbox)
8UC3 rows:4 cols:5
2) frameROIProcessed
8UC3 rows:4 cols:5


1) outputFrame(ROIbox)
8UC3 rows:27 cols:22
2) frameROIProcessed
8UC3 rows:27 cols:22


OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() == Size(_cols, _rows)) in cv::debug_build_guard::_OutputArray::create, file d:\applications\opencv\source\opencv-master\modules\core\src\matrix_wrap.cpp, line 1227
OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize() || ((Mat*)obj)->size.operator()() == Size(_cols, _rows)) in cv::debug_build_guard::_OutputArray::create, file d:\applications\opencv\source\opencv-master\modules\core\src\matrix_wrap.cpp, line 1227
```

**Update**: I tried the same code in a non-multithreaded format and it worked. Now I am not sure why the function is not thread safe even if I do the below (I still get the same error, but I think I made sure that only one instance of the function is running at one time):

```
    if (isFrameBeingProcessed) {
        return;
    }
    isFrameBeingProcessed = true;
    frame.copyTo(outputFrame);

    if (ROIbox.width != 0 && ROIbox.height != 0) {
        rectangle(outputFrame, Point(ROIbox.x, ROIbox.y), cvPoint(ROIbox.x + ROIbox.width, ROIbox.y + ROIbox.height), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1);
    }

    Mat frameROI = frame(ROIbox);

    if (frameROI.rows != 0 && frameROI.cols != 0) {
        Mat frameROIProcessed;
        cvtColor(frameROI, frameROIProcessed, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        inRange(frameROIProcessed, Scalar(hueLow, saturationLow, brightnessLow), Scalar(hueHigh, saturationHigh, brightnessHigh), frameROIProcessed);
        cvtColor(frameROIProcessed, frameROIProcessed, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

        qInfo("1) outputFrame(ROIbox)");
        qInfo(getImageType(outputFrame(ROIbox)).c_str());
        qInfo("2) frameROIProcessed");
        qInfo(getImageType(frameROIProcessed).c_str());
        qInfo((string("Box x: ")+to_string(ROIbox.x) + string(", y: ") + to_string(ROIbox.y) + string(", width: ") + to_string(ROIbox.width) + string(", height: ") + to_string(ROIbox.height)).c_str());
        qInfo((string("Mat width: ") + to_string(outputFrame(ROIbox).cols) + string(", height: ") + to_string(outputFrame(ROIbox).rows)).c_str());
        qInfo("\n");
        frameROIProcessed.copyTo(outputFrame(ROIbox));
    }
    cvtColor(outputFrame, outputFrame, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    isFrameBeingProcessed = false;
```

Comment: Using VS debugger, determine which line throws exception.

Comment: @zindarod It is at `frameROIProcessed.copyTo(outputFrame(ROIbox))`. Updated my post with this information.

Comment: I also verify that `copyTo` has both images of the same size and type

Comment: Test the `processFrame()` function outside of `receiveTimerTick()` function in a single threaded environment.

Comment: @Micka You can scroll the message horizontally to see it in full. That is the whole message and there was nothing else.

Comment: can you make your ::receiveTimerTick function thread-safe? You must make sure that processFrame has finished before the timer function is called again, because the frame memory will be altered.

Comment: @Micka zindarod It works in a non-multithreaded version. Now I tried another piece of code trying to make sure that only one instance of the function is running at any time (updated the post above for the new code). I still have the same errors. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I displayed debugging statements on the console at every step and found what the problem was. The problem was that ROIbox was not thread-safe (thanks @zindarod and @Micka). The GUI which gives the region of interest box `ROIbox` is on a different thread and `ROIbox` changes size during the processing of the frame. The simple fix was to add `Rect_<int> box = ROIbox;` in the beginning of the function `processFrame()` and to use this copied box in the function.